# main div with 2 divs, 1 in middle and one right of it

Tags: html, css

[image: http://imgur.com/7Z31wwv]

I want it like in this picture,

div header has 2 divs inside of it, div logo should be in middle, and div info should be right of it with some margin.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header{ width:100%; height:100px;}

#logo{ width:33%; float:right; height:100px;}

#info{ width:33%; float:right; height:100px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get this sort of layout a few ways.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4cBRe8JZrQDYoDglfcVW?p=preview

The method show here is done by setting percentages for the widths in the header, everything should responsibly adjust to screen changes.

```
#header #logo{
    width: 33%;
    margin-right: -4px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    display:inline-block;
}

#header #info{
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display:inline-block;
}
```